# How to query from Postgres DB created with Prisma in Vercel interface?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma, vercel

All my tables were created using prisma and here's a model example:

```
model Story {
  id         String   @id @default(cuid())
  title      String   @unique
  tags       String[]
  category   String
  created_by String
  private    Boolean  @default(true)
  rate       String
  content    Bytes
  Category   Category @relation(fields: [category], references: [id])
  Creator    User     @relation(fields: [created_by], references: [id])
}
```

Sometimes I want to use Vercel interface to do a quick query to check something but I couldn't find how. I'm trying `SELECT * FROM Story` and getting `Syntax error: relation "story" does not exist.`. If I try it `SELECT * FROM story` I get the same error.

Using Prisma API (prisma.story.findAll) works just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried doing the query with the schema name? eg: public."Story"

Comment: @Zxeenu that worked, thanks!